# Qt: Signals and slots Error: undefined reference to `vtable for

Tags: qt, signals-slots, vtable, undefined-reference

Following example from this link: http://developer.kde.org/documentation/books/kde-2.0-development/ch03lev1sec3.html

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT  // Enable slots and signals
    public:
        MyWindow();
    private slots:
        void slotButton1();
        void slotButton2();
        void slotButtons();
    private:
        QPushButton *button1;
        QPushButton *button2;
};

MyWindow :: MyWindow() : QWidget()
{
    // Create button1 and connect button1->clicked() to this->slotButton1()
    button1 = new QPushButton("Button1", this);
    button1->setGeometry(10,10,100,40);
    button1->show();
    connect(button1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slotButton1()));

    // Create button2 and connect button2->clicked() to this->slotButton2()
    button2 = new QPushButton("Button2", this);
    button2->setGeometry(110,10,100,40);
    button2->show();
    connect(button2, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slotButton2()));

    // When any button is clicked, call this->slotButtons()
    connect(button1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slotButtons()));
    connect(button2, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slotButtons()));
}

// This slot is called when button1 is clicked.
void MyWindow::slotButton1()
{
    cout << "Button1 was clicked" << endl;
}

// This slot is called when button2 is clicked
void MyWindow::slotButton2()
{
    cout << "Button2 was clicked" << endl;
}

// This slot is called when any of the buttons were clicked
void MyWindow::slotButtons()
{
    cout << "A button was clicked" << endl;
}

int main ()
{
    MyWindow a;
}
```

results in:

```
    [13:14:34 Mon May 02] ~/junkPrograms/src/nonsense  $make
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/opt/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/opt/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/include/QtCore -I/opt/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/include/QtGui -I/opt/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/include -I. -I. -o signalsSlots.o signalsSlots.cpp
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/lib -o nonsense signalsSlots.o    -L/opt/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/lib -lQtGui -L/opt/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lQtCore -lpthread
signalsSlots.o: In function `MyWindow::MyWindow()':
signalsSlots.cpp:(.text+0x1a2): undefined reference to `vtable for MyWindow'
signalsSlots.cpp:(.text+0x1aa): undefined reference to `vtable for MyWindow'
signalsSlots.o: In function `MyWindow::MyWindow()':
signalsSlots.cpp:(.text+0x3e2): undefined reference to `vtable for MyWindow'
signalsSlots.cpp:(.text+0x3ea): undefined reference to `vtable for MyWindow'
signalsSlots.o: In function `main':
signalsSlots.cpp:(.text+0x614): undefined reference to `vtable for MyWindow'
signalsSlots.o:signalsSlots.cpp:(.text+0x61d): more undefined references to `vtable for MyWindow' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [nonsense] Error 1
```

vtable is for virtual functions, AFAIK, what's the reason of error here?

Comment: I don't see what is the problem, but I would like to point out that the tutorial you are using is rather outdated. I suggest you look at the tutorials in Qt 4.7 documentation.

Comment: @ypnos thanks but the tut on 4.7 doesn't show any "running" example, which I could just paste and run :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt moc with implementations inside of header files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001615/qt-moc-with-implementations-inside-of-header-files)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to vtable. Trying to compile a Qt project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552069/undefined-reference-to-vtable-trying-to-compile-a-qt-project)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It looks like moc doesn't generate code for your `QObject` because you declare it in the `.cpp` file. The easiest way to fix that is to move the declaration of `MyWindow` to a header, and add the header to the `HEADERS` list, in the *.pro* file:

```
HEADERS += yourheader.h
```

Then rerun `qmake`.

(Please note that the KDE 2.0 book you look at is vastly outdated)

Comment: Thanks for responding, but is there no way by which I can keep the declaration and the definition in the .cpp file?

Comment: Try with HEADERS += your.cpp . Generally, although possible, I find QObject declarations so much pain that I prefer to have them (private) headers instead. Which works fine with all buildsystems, be it qmake, cmake, ...

Comment: Thanks again, I seperated the .h, .cpp and main :mad: and it solved the error, I haven't yet studied details regarding moc file.

Comment: Whenever you declare a QObject inside a filename.cpp file, you should add `#include "filename.moc"` to the end of your .cpp file and qmake will do the right thing for you. This is the common practice in KDE, for example.

Comment: Excellent answer. It's annoying that Qt imposes extra limitations above C++ itself but I guess I can live with that.

Answer (score 24):

Maybe too late but... Had the same issue and fighted for a while to find where it comes from.

Right click on your project and select “Run qmake” to for a new build of MOC classes. It usually does run automatically...

The moc compiler generates the stubs and calls in moc_xxxx.cpp, and generates the vtable stuff

Comment: I don't use qtcreator. I do run qmake many times before asking here. It didn't help.

Comment: @AnishaKaul Likewise.  Running `qmake` for me does not fix anything.  If i run `qmake --project` then it regenerates the `.pro` and I can compile, but that hoses all the changes people have made to the `.pro`, which is really bad.

Comment: 1++ this fix my problem

Comment: After adding Q_OBJECT to .h file and run qmake, It worked +1

Answer (score 1):

Just Change your Main() as follows:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyWindow w;

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on andref comment just above, when everything is in one cpp file like `stuff.cpp`, you need to add at the end of the file:

```
#include "moc_stuff.cpp"
```

(this is with Qt 4.7.0)

Comment: Using Qt 4.8, this did not work for me. I had to do what the referred-to comment suggests.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be caused by some of the following reasons. I have stumbled on all of them from time to time.

---

Your class header may be missing the Q_OBJECT macro. Add the macro to the header as already noted by other answers.

```
class MyWidg : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
```

---

Your class header may not be parsed by the moc. Add the header file in the HEADERS definitions of your .pro (or .pri) project file.

```
HEADERS += file.h
```

---

If none of the above is true, then you probably need to run qmake again to make sure moc parses the header again, just in case the Q_OBJECT macro was added in the header after the qmake was run. Just run qmake again.