# Declare a widget in .cpp file

Tags: qt

I have a class extending `QWidget`

```
 class Boo : public QWidget {
      Q_OBJECT
 public:
      Boo(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent) {}
 };
```

If I just add it to cpp file I get the following error:

...`` [Boo::Boo(QWidget*)]+0x71): undefined reference to `vtable for Boo' ``

Why does it happen?

Is it possible to add the class to .cpp file anyway?

Comment: Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854626/qt-signals-and-slots-error-undefined-reference-to-vtable-for)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001615/qt-moc-with-implementations-inside-of-header-files

Answer (score 0):

An answer is that you definitely can add such declarations in *.cpp files, there is nothing wrong with it, but you should not forget to MOC *.cpp files, so appropriate *_moc.cpp file which be generated and checked that it's included in the project. if you are using qmake you should be fine, if you are using VisualStudio you should regenerate VS project file.

Main reason is for this error is that you don't have *_moc.cpp file wither generated or included in the project.

Comment: Do you mean I should have moc_Boo.cpp file?
If yes, can I add its creation to the .pro file?

Comment: Exactly. If you have your cpp file declared in .pro file in sources, then it will be created automatically as well as added to makefile/solution

Answer (score -1):

No you cannot add the class just to the .cpp file in build systems MOC'ing only header files. The class declaration needs to be located in a header file that is MOC'ed by the build system.

Comment: Yes, you can do it in a `.cpp` file. See linked question.

Comment: Entirely different question is, if *should* do it in a `.cpp` file... Usually not, unless its for an SSCCE or something like that.

Comment: @hyde: I added a little wording which guards my statement from disadvantageous interpretation I hope?

Comment: Hmm, and which build system would not moc .cpp file?